# Variable losing value (feed rss xamarin)

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to make my variable receive value found in my search in the feed, but when I go to check if there is something the variable is empty, the value is being passed by and the same information that generates in my list

command list feed

```
    private Command loadItemsCommand;
    public Command LoadItemsCommand
    {
        get { return loadItemsCommand ?? (loadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand())); }
    }

    private async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;

        IsBusy = true;
        var error = false;
        try
        {
            var responseString = string.Empty;
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                var feed = "url feed";
                responseString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(feed);
            }

            var items = await ParseFeed(responseString);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                FeedItems.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            error = true;
        }

        if (error)
        {
            var page = new ContentPage();
            await page.DisplayAlert("Error", "Unable to load blog.", "OK");
        }

        IsBusy = false;
    }

private async Task<List<FeedItem>> ParseFeed(string rss)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(rss);
            var id = 0;
            return (from item in xdoc.Descendants("item")
                    let enclosure = item.Element("enclosure")
                    where enclosure != null
                    select new FeedItem
                    {
                        Title = (string)item.Element("title"),
                        Description = (string)item.Element("description"),
                        Link = (string)item.Element("link"),
                        PublishDate = DateTime.Parse((string)item.Element("pubDate")).ToUniversalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),
                        Category = (string)item.Element("category"),
                        Mp3Url = (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"),
                        Image = (string)enclosure.Attribute("url"),
                        Color_category = "#" + Convert.ToString(int.Parse((string)item.Element("color")), 16).PadLeft(6, '0'),
                        Id = id++
                    }).Skip(0).Take(1).ToList();
        });
    }
```

class

```
    public class FeedItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set { title = value; }
    }
}
```

load "**FeedItem m = new FeedItem(); teste.Text = m.Title;**" Nothing returns to me

```
public feed()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new BlogFeedViewModel();
        ***FeedItem m = new FeedItem();
        teste.Text = m.Title;***

        listView.ItemTapped += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (listView.SelectedItem == null)
                return;
            this.Navigation.PushAsync(new PodcastPlaybackPage(listView.SelectedItem as FeedItem));
            listView.SelectedItem = null;
        };
    }
```

Comment: you are never calling ParseFeed(), you are just creating an empty FeedItem.

Comment: This command is running, because in my list the item appears, I edited the command, make sure that I am calling

Comment: then there must be other code that does that.  But in the two specific lines you are asking about, you are simply creating a new object and then checking it's properties without ever setting their values.

Comment: Was some mistake even somewhere, re-made the command and it worked